# How to vectorize double loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, nested-loops

```
y = 0;

for m = 0:variable
  for n = 0:m
    y = y + f(n,m);
  end
end
```

I vectorized the inner loop this way,

```
y = 0;

for m = 0:variable
  n = 0:m
  y = y + f(n,m);
end
```

This resulted in around 60% speed increase for my code. How do I also vectorize the outer loop?

Comment: You loop is equivalent to simply `y = f(variable, variable)`... are you sure you didn't mean to assign to `y(m+1)`...?

Comment: You constantly overwrite y with the output of f, so only the final iteration does anything.  Is f an array or a function?  If a function, then how one "vectorizes" depends entirely on what f is doing.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your function `f`? Can both parameters be vectors? What are the constraints? What is the output of `f` if you pass a vector argument to it?

Comment: It always depends on your problem, if you can substitute the loop with a vector-operation. So as one said: What's your real problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `meshgrid` function.  It is designed to fill in the sort of m by n combinations that it looks like you need.  For example:

```
>> m = 1:4;
>> n = 1:3;
>> [mGridValues, nGridValues] = meshgrid(m,n)
mGridValues =
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
nGridValues =
     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3
```

This is a little more complicated since your inner loop depends on the value of your outer loop.  So you will need to mask out the undesired [n, m] pairs (see below).

Modifying the prototype code that you have provided, you would end up with something like this:

```
[mValues, nValues] = meshgrid(0:variable, 0:variable);  %Start with a full combination of values

mask = mValues >= nValues;  %Identify all values where m >= n
mValues = mValues(mask);    %    And then remove pairs which do not
nValues = nValues(mask);    %    meet this criteria

y = f(nValues, mValues );   %Perform whatever work you are performing here
```

Comment: How much time all this code is reduced according to your loops...?